# Simulation terminated with exit code: 139

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using OMNeT++ 4.6, SUMO-0.21.0 and Veins-4a2 on Ubuntu-16.0.4. I was able to run this simulation on Windows 10 perfectly. Now, I am trying to run this simulation on Ubuntu, but I am getting an error. The console output is:

```
...
Assigned runID=General-0-20190104-16:31:45-11727
Setting up network `FranciscoScenario'...
Simulation terminated with exit code: 139
Working directory: /home/gowher/veins-4a2/examples/veins
Command line: opp_run -r 0 -u Cmdenv -n .:../../src/veins --tkenv-image-path=../../images -l ../../src/veins omnetpp.ini
Environment variables:
...
```

Interestingly, if SUMO is not running, I do not get this error. In that case, I get "Traci server not found" error as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exit code means you have a memory access bug in your code. You might want to use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find the issue in your code. There is an answer on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/omnetpp/_zonGWenUqg/FQaHMRY9-dkJ) that might help you.

> Interestingly, if SUMO is not running, I do not get this error. In that case I get "Traci server not found" error as expected.

This is because your simulation is not even starting as SUMO is not running. This error is clear and obvious.